# Fork array assignment conflict

Tags: c, arrays, fork

I have the following and try to read from file line by line and then put that line to an array.

```
char **history = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1000);
int history_size = 0;

fp = fopen(file, "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    if(strstr(line, "\n") != NULL) {
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    if (strcmp(line, "History") == 0) {
        for(int m = 0; m < history_size; m++) {
            printf("%s\n", history[m]);
        }
    } else {
        //printf("....%s\n", line);
        history[history_size++] = line;
    }
}

fclose(fp);
if (line)
    free(line);
```

Problem is that array does not collect lines and when I run the code it prints "History" as many as lines in the file.  I could not handle it for days. History should keep the lines that occurs before History line.

Comment: Better way to remove trailing newline from `getline()` or `fgets()`:  `line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`  See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.3

Comment: What is `runcmd`?

Comment: it contains execvp if(fork() == 0)

Comment: Why are you passing in `fork()` as an argument? That's *really* odd to see. Normally you either call or don't call the function. This effectively makes two calls. Calling `fork()` inside of that function then splits into three processes.

Comment: I just want to handle fork in a function. No problem at that side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `fork()`.

From the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) of `getline`:

> If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program. (In this case, the value in *n is ignored.)
>
> If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.

The problem is that you are assigning the address to the array elements. At last they all point to the same address(depends on `getline`'s `realloc`). As you didn't `malloc`, so `getline` must have done that internally, and on subsequent calls `realloc` is used inside `getline` which would generally retain the same address. So over the loop as your `line` is updated, all array elements are likely to be updated as well because most array elements point to the same address.

So finally when you reach the condition when your `line` is `"History"`, they just showed what `line` contained (i.e. "History") because all of them pointed to the same address as `line`.

This is the main cause of problem, but `fork()` would surely deviate you from the way you want your output afterwards. Although `fork()` would only disturb your output and can be easily handled by not printing when `fork()` returned `0`.

Corrections:

1) As you told in comments on your question you are doing `execvp()` if `fork() == 0`, it shouldn't cause problems. All you need to do is:

```
history[history_size] = malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(line)+1));
strcpy(history[history_size++], line);
```

instead of directly assigning it.

2) Remember to `free()` on every iteration the memory allocated by `getline()` in `line`.

Comment: what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: @Davis, it totally depends on your scenario. If you want to stick to them same way as your code is, instead of assigning directly to array elements, do like `history[history_size] = malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(line)+1)); strcpy(history[history_size++], line);`. Although as you are using `fork()` , that too would cause additional troubles that you need to handle.

Comment: If you could give some overview of what exactly you want to achive, maybe better ways can be suggested.